# Why am I getting a 0 at the beginning of my output?

Tags: python-3.10

```
person_name = ''
person_age = 0
person_name = str(input(person_name))
person_age = int(input(person_age))
print('In 5 years', person_name, 'will be', person_age + 5)
```

My output always has a zero at the beginning and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

The `input()` function in python can take an optional argument `input(prompt)`
where `prompt` is a String, representing a default message before the input.

For your code you can just write

```py
person_name = str(input())
person_age = int(input())
print('In 5 years', person_name, 'will be', person_age + 5)
```

Or

```py
person_name = str(input('Enter your name:'))
person_age = int(input('Enter your age:'))
print('In 5 years', person_name, 'will be', person_age + 5)
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 0 at the beginning of the output because person_age is set to 0, and you pass it as the prompt message to input().

If person_name was not an empty string, you would see that one first.

The correct code is this:

```
person_name = ''
person_age = 0
person_name = input("Enter name: ")
person_age = int(input("Enter age: "))
print('In 5 years', person_name, 'will be', person_age + 5)
```